# How to get Detailed information with SQL Exceptions in Android

Tags: android

We are using SQLite for Database in our Android Application. If anytime insert command fails we just get a return value of -1 means insert not successful , but with return value of -1 it is hard to debug why call was failed.

We are planning to use DB Lib (ORM) like Green DAO or REALM or active android. Does any of these  libs provide us information like why insert is failed if there's a SQLException reported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should print something out to logcat.  But if you want to be more certain, use insertOrThrow and check out the exception.